# write special characters in file using php

Tags: php, file

I am writting one .txt file using php. When I create it with some special charecter then it shows Ascii code for that. Like if I write a string "I don`t know" it shows "I don&#39;t know". how to write it as human redable format?

code is below

```
function WriteErrorLog($IntegrationId, $errorStr){
    // get integration name--------


    $integrationnameQuery = "select * from integration where IntegrationId = $IntegrationId";
    $queryRes = mysql_query($integrationnameQuery);
    $resRows = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes);
    $integrationName = $resRows['Name'];
    if(!file_exists('errors/'.$IntegrationId.'/'.date("Y.m.d").'_ErrorFile.txt')){
        $errorFile = 'errors/'.$IntegrationId.'/'.date("Y.m.d").'_ErrorFile.txt';
        $fh = fopen($errorFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, 'Integration Name: '.$integrationName."\r\n\r\n".date('Y-m-d H:i:s').': '.$errorStr."\r\n\r\n");
        fclose($fh);
    }else{
        $errorFile = 'errors/'.$IntegrationId.'/'.date("Y.m.d").'_ErrorFile.txt';
        $fh = fopen($errorFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, date('Y-m-d H:i:s').': '.$errorStr."\r\n\r\n");
        fclose($fh);
    }
}

function CreateErrorLog($IntegrationId, $errorStr){
    if (!is_dir('./errors/'.$IntegrationId)) {
        mkdir('./errors/'.$IntegrationId);
        WriteErrorLog($IntegrationId, $errorStr);
    }else{
        WriteErrorLog($IntegrationId,  $errorStr);
    }
}
```

I am accessing like below

```
CreateErrorLog('120', 'I don`t know');
```

Comment: What are you doing now? Show your code.

Comment: could you show your not working code ...?

Comment: Without seeing any code, I would say you may just need to escape the character. i.e. `"I don\'t know"`. But like a say, your issue may be unrelated.

Comment: post your code so that we can help u.

Answer (score 1):

You can write special haracters by special codes: for example \n is 0x0A

Or you can use function chr() for convert from ASCII code to character.

Or you can use %c in (f|s)printf functions. `printf("There is zero:%c", 0x30);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` in your code, remove it.